# How to fix lightbox width and height

Tags: css

I'm using lightbox slideshow, the lightbox width and height vary as per images width and height ,i want to fix the width and height of lightbox so that it should not vary,please can suggest.

Comment: Are you using Justin Barkhuff's lightbox slideshow ?

Comment: Fathima, could you give us a link to which slideshow you are refering to?

Answer (score -1):

Through JQuery you can fix this as per the below format,

```
$('.YOURCLASS').lightBox({
        maxHeight: SETMAXHEIGHT,
        maxWidth: SETMAXWIDTH
});
```

Comment: but this height and width can still decrease if it is less than maxheight and maxwidth values. It is not fixed then.